# How to create custom annotation and callout bubble in iphone?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to create a customized annotation and callout bubble on MKMapView. I need to use a customized view rather than default annotation pin and annotaion view(which is limited to show only title and a single line description). When user tap on an annotation, I would like to display more information on the callout bubble.

Comment: Did you end up finding a good solution?

Comment: yes. I found a solution which suitable for my requirement. The way i have done is, i have created a custom annotation class which is a subclass of MKAnnotationView and in the "- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated" method i have created my own view(UIView).

Answer (score 0):

I passed by this control but I haven't used it:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/custom-callout

I've found some pretty good controls at that site.